# Does zinc help with colds and flus?

Tags: medical-science, common-cold, flu, zinc

This question doesn't duplicate [the more limited one on Zicam](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/831/16959); I ask here about zinc in general.

**No:** [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/common-cold/expert-answers/zinc-for-colds/faq-20057769) (from which I quote below) and [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/cold-and-flu/cold-guide/zinc-lozenges-cold-remedy) are skeptical.

> Since then, research has turned up mixed results about zinc and colds

**Possibly yes:** See [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/news/2012/05may/Pages/Zinc-shortens-common-cold.aspx)  (from which I quote below)  and [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/journalists/sarah-knapton/10600246/Zinc-not-Vitamin-C-is-best-for-fighting-colds.html) .

> For many years, it has been suggested that zinc supplements could relieve the symptoms of the common cold, but there was little clarity until a 2011 evidence review. This recent review suggested a modest reduction in the length of symptoms, although the results were not entirely conclusive. In a bid to help clarify the matter, researchers have conducted another review of evidence on this issue.

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate of http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/243/are-zinc-supplements-beneficial?

Comment: @Oddthinking That question doesn't appear to discuss zinc's effects on illnesses?

Comment: The sources you provide *say basically the same thing*, there's no controversy and the claim that "zinc may help" is backed by a systematic review with specific caveats. These results are clearly explained e.g. in the NHS article.

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze Thanks, but I seek a definitive, unequivocal answer? The model verb 'may' implies doubt or subjectivity?

Comment: The site is for challenging notable claims: what notable claim are you challenging? *There is no claim that there is a unequivocal answer*